# Is there a serious issue with setting the SUID bit on tcpdump?

Tags: security, permissions, tcpdump

I'm running tcpdump on a remote machine, and piping the output to Wireshark on my local machine over SSH. In order to do this, I had to set the SUID bit on tcpdump.

For background, the remote machine is an Amazon EC2 running "Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09". On this image, there is no root password, and it is not possible to log in as root. You can't use sudo without a TTY, and therefore you have to set the SUID.

What are the practical risks of setting this bit on tcpdump? Is there any need to be paranoid? Should I unset it whenever I'm not capturing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that everyone who has shell access to this machine may use `tcpdump` to capture the traffic. The paranoia is not the bad thing when we are talking about security. You may forget eventually that you set it suid and at some day you will give the shell access to someone who you can't trust to the full extent. I believe, you don't want this. I think you should consider to use `sudo` to run `tcpdump` from your account. It is possible to set the `sudo` not to prompt for a password for specific user and for specific commands.

Comment: This is a single purpose machine, and anyone who logs in will need root access. `sudo` won't work because you can't use it without being logged into the machine (I'm running tcpdump by passing it as an argument to ssh). Thanks, I just wanted to make sure that it didn't pose an external security problem.

Comment: then why you can't use `ssh user@machine sudo tcpdump eth0` for example?

Comment: This returns `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: You need to configure the sudo according to your needs. Take a look at `man sudo` if you interested in making it working for you

Comment: For the tty issue try this : ssh -t user@machine sudo tcpdump eth0

Comment: @Valor This works perfectly with your example. However, the exact command I'm running is `$ wireshark -k -i <(ssh user@machine tcpdump eth0 -w -)`. This allows me to view the live tcpdump capture on the remote machine locally in Wireshark. With the `-t` switch, I get the error "Unrecognized libpcap format" in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment request, here is how I have it working to pipe remote tcpdump through sudo to wireshark:

```
ssh user@host sudo tcpdump -s0 -w - | wireshark -k -i -
```

Notes: I've added s0 to capture the entire packets.

Just made a wrapper script that runs exactly that but you only need to give the ssh credentials and an optional filter for tcpdump. You can download it from  [here](https://raw.github.com/guruHub/scripts/master/networking/remote-wireshark.sh)

Comment: I appreciate the effort Valor, but unfortunately this results in the same error described above (sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo, or the Wireshark error if I use -t).

Comment: @Dean what os and what shell are you running ? I've just tried that from debian & ubuntu against an EC2 Instance (Ubuntu 10.04) and it worked ok.

Comment: @Dean Check /etc/sudoers on your EC2 instance, if there it's a line saying requiretty remove it or comment it.

Comment: That works. However, it warns that it will show the password in clear. Does this have any advantage over setting the SUID bit on tcpdump?

Comment: @Dean "it will show the password" ? Where are you using a password?

Comment: You're right, I don't need a password for sudo. To be honest both methods seem harmless to me, but I'm not sure if there's something I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @Dean AFAIK a binary with suid bit set it's far far more dangerous than allowing sudoers configured users to execute a command in a non interactive fashion (that's what requiretty it's for). Also keep in mind [you can disable requiretty just for your user](http://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user).